# Completion block isn't called when updating UIPageViewController during rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, screen-rotation

I'm trying to update the current page in `UIPageViewController` during rotation as following:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    NSArray *controllers = @[someViewController];
    UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward;

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:controllers direction:direction animated:YES completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        /// This completion block isn't called ever in this case.
    }];
}
```

But, for some reason, the completion block isn't called ever in this case, while it's called as expected when I call the same method with same parameters from other places.

Could anyone confirm this strange behavior, and if it's a bug in `UIPageViewController` or just a misuse of me?

***Update***

I found out that if I change the parameter `animated` to `NO` the completion block will be called as expected! So, it seems more to me that it's a bug with `UIPageViewController`.

Comment: In my case I had the problem when I tried to set the same controller I already had in self.pageViewController.viewControllers.firstObject

Answer (score 8):

Having the same issue, found the following thing: if `someViewController` is the current visible controller or `pageController.viewControllers?.first` and `animated` flag is set to true, then `setViewControllers` is called without invoking the completion handler. The easiest way is to call `setViewControllers` with `animated` flag set to false. No animations will be shown, but the completion handler will be invoked anyway. But in most cases you need animations to be shown. Thus, the only possible workaround here is to check if the viewController to be set isn't the visible one. If it is, you should call `setViewControllers` with `animated` flag set to false:

```
let completionBlock: (Bool) -> Void
let isAnimated = (newController != pageController.viewControllers?.first)

pageController.setViewControllers([newController],
                                  direction: .forward,
                                  animated: isAnimated, 
                                  completion: completionBlock)
```

Hope that helps you!

Answer (score 2):

If keeping the animation is needed, an another option is to wrap in `UIView.animation` which provides an animation completion callback. That callback will be called regardless of rotation and will actually indicate if the setViewControllers animation was cancelled due to a rotation.

**Here's an extension method that encapsulates the solution:**

```
extension UIPageViewController {
    
    /// A drop-in replacement of `setViewControllers`. It fixes `viewControllers` not displaying properly
    /// if the change animation was cancelled by iOS, which happens everytime the device is rotated.
    ///
    /// See `UIPageViewController.setViewControllers` for parameter details.
    ///
    /// More Info: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19268005/2191796
    @objc
    func setViewControllersPatched(_ viewControllers: [UIViewController]?, direction: UIPageViewController.NavigationDirection, animated: Bool, completion: ((Bool) -> Void)?) {
        if animated {
            // Track if completion gets called - since it's not guaranteed
            // See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19268005/2191796
            var wasCompletionCalled = false
            
            // Wrap in an animation block with it's own completion block that is guaranteed and will indicate if the inner animation gets cancelled
            // The duration needs to be longer than the `setViewControllers` animation, otherwise `animationWasCancelled` will always be true.
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4) {
                self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: direction, animated: animated) { animationSkippedByUser in
                    wasCompletionCalled = true
                    
                    completion?(animationSkippedByUser)
                }
            } completion: { animationWasCancelled in
                // When `setViewControllers` is called and a rotation occurs, `animationWasCancelled` will be true - since iOS cancelled the animation.
                if animationWasCancelled && !wasCompletionCalled {
                    print("UIPageViewController.setViewControllersPatched: Issue detected with canceled animation, fixing by setting view controllers without animation.")
                    self.setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: completion)
                }
            }
        } else {
            // There is no layout/rotation issue when there is no animation - So just pass on the parameters
            setViewControllers(viewControllers, direction: direction, animated: animated, completion: completion)
        }
    }
}
```

**How to Use:**

Replace `setViewControllers` with `setViewControllersPatched`.

Answer (score -2):

try it as:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self newMethod];
  // or  [self performSelector:@selector(newMethod) withObject:self afterDelay:0.01];
}

- (void)newMethod{
    NSArray *controllers = @[someViewController];
    UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward;

    [self.pageController setViewControllers:controllers direction:direction animated:YES          completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        ///
    }];
}
```

Comment: What's the difference here?

Comment: because you doing this in delegate method. if you do it like this. it will be called from saparat method. if this also not work .try it with  perforselector with delay 0.01.

Comment: Moving the code to a new method and just calling that method doesn't mean it'll be executed in another thread. Nevertheless, I just want to  know if it's a bug with `UIPageViewController` or a misuse of me.

Comment: did you try it ? ok do it as you think